# if it possible send build via beta-crashlytics for testers in different time

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

I use beta-crashlytics for deliver app to testers.I have few group of users and i want to deliver build in different time for them: to tester group asap, to customers group after testing. But can't find this settings in beta . Does anybody knows if it possible use different settings of delivering build for different groups?